# unable to convert plain array into jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

On load I have to disable the NEXT button, but for that I have to convert my plain array into jquery array.

http://jsfiddle.net/2hBUq/1/

I tried but its showing some strange value in console. So please help me with this

html

```
<div id="wholeRecipeIds">
    [3618, 5143, 5144, 5146, 9728, 16497, 4002, 4852, 2864, 32661]
</div>
 <input id="next" width="100px" type="button"  value="Next">
```

jquery

```
var nextRowIndex = '32661'; 
var wholeRecipes=$("#wholeRecipeIds").html();
var recipArray = jQuery.makeArray(wholeRecipes); 
var lastRecipeId =  recipArray[recipArray.length-1];

console.log("New array recips:"+recipArray);   
console.log("size of array recipe:"+recipArray.length);   
console.log("lastRecipeId in array :"+lastRecipeId);  
if(nextRowIndex==lastRecipeId){
   $("#next").attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

output:(wrong output for "size of array recipe & lastRecipeId variable)

```
New array recips:
    [3618, 5143, 5144, 5146, 9728, 16497, 4002, 4852, 2864, 32661]
 (index):28
size of array recipe:1 
lastRecipeId in array :
    [3618, 5143, 5144, 5146, 9728, 16497, 4002, 4852, 2864, 32661]
```

Why this strange output.

Comment: can you understand my question, if not please reply me

Comment: It is taking the whole string of numbers and putting it into the first index of the array. You need to split that string of numbers to make an array.

Comment: makeArray expect object param, you gave him a string... try JSON.parse()

Comment: This is `recipArray` right now: `["\n    [3618, 5143, 5144, 5146, 9728, 16497, 4002, 4852, 2864, 32661]\n"]`. [`jQuery.makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) turns an array-like object into an array, not a string into an array like `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: On load of page you need to disable next button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not starting off with an array; you're starting with a **string**.  The contents of the `<div>` are read as just one simple string. If you want it to be interpreted as an array, you can feed it to the JSON parser:

```
    var wholeRecipes = JSON.parse($("#wholeRecipeIds").html());
```

There's not really any need to do this:

```
    var recipArray = jQuery.makeArray(wholeRecipes);
```

Once you've parsed the raw contents of your element, you'll have a JavaScript array. There's really no such thing as a "jQuery array", and that's not what that API is for.

Comment: The `.makeArray()` API is for things like `arguments` or `NodeList` instances; things that have numerically-indexed properties and a `.length` property.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.makeArray()` turns an array-like object into an array

Use `JSON.parse()` to convert a **string**  into an array.

Try:

```
var recipArray = JSON.parse(wholeRecipes);
```

instead of

```
var recipArray = jQuery.makeArray(wholeRecipes);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2hBUq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**makeArray** Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array.

```
    var nextRowIndex = '32661'
        wholeRecipes=$("#wholeRecipeIds").html(),
        recipArray = $.parseJSON(wholeRecipes), 
        lastRecipeId = recipArray[recipArray.length-1];

    console.log("New array recips:"+recipArray);   
    console.log("size of array recipe:"+recipArray.length);   
    console.log("lastRecipeId in array :"+lastRecipeId);  
    if(nextRowIndex==lastRecipeId){
       $("#next").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
```